# A power series solution to Hermite's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, hermite-polynomials

I'm trying to solve the Hermite's differential equation

\begin{equation*}
y''(x)-2xy'(x)+2ny(x) = 0
\end{equation*}

I look for power series solutions of the form

\begin{equation}
y(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty a_\nu x^\nu
\end{equation}

Then I found the recurrence,

\begin{equation}
a_{\nu+2} = \frac{2(\nu-n)}{(\nu+2)(\nu+1)} a_\nu
\label{eq:anHer}
\end{equation}
for $\nu = 0,...,n$.

So i am looking for even and odd powers of x solutions. For the even solutions I have

\begin{equation}
a_{2k} = \frac{4\left(k-1-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{2k(2k-1)}a_{2(k-1)}
\end{equation}
for $k = 1,2,...$

In terms of $a_0$ I have,
\begin{align*}
&a_2=\frac{4(-\frac{n}{2})}{2\cdot1}a_0\\
&a_4 =\frac{4\left(1-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{4\cdot3}a_2 = \frac{4^2\left(1-\frac{n}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}a_0   \\
& a_6 = \frac{4\left(2-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{6\cdot5}a_4 =\frac{4^3\left(2-\frac{n}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{n}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}a_0 \\
\vdots\\
&a_{2k} = \frac{2^{2k}(-\frac{n}{2})_k}{(2k)!}a_0
\end{align*}
where $(x)_\mu$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Then the even solutions are
\begin{equation}
y_{even}(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_{2k}x^{2k} = a_0\left(1+ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2k}(-\frac{n}{2})_k}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right)
\end{equation}
in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html the even solutions are given by
\begin{equation}
y_{2n}(x) = c_0 \left(1+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{2k}(-n)_k}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right)
\end{equation}

I don't see why I have $(-\frac{n}{2})_k$ instead of $(-n)_k$. Since the series I've obtained terminates for $k = 1+\frac{n}{2}$ maybe I can truncate the series and write my series in this form but I'm not sure. Or maybe is just because the normalization of $c_0$ given in the previous link, which is $c_0= (-1)^n2^n(2n-1)!!$, while my $a_0$ is a general normalization constant without a particular expression so is a ''more general'' solution.